# Creating a Tomato Timer

Tags: javascript, timer

I have completed a FreeCodeCamp exercise to create a tomato timer and chosen to do so with vanilla Javascript. Although it works, I don't like in how many places I am checking against two state variables `onBreak` and `isPaused` in many areas of the application.

```js
 (function() {

   "use strict";


   // Initialisation
   var breakLength = 300;
   var sessionLength = 1500;
   var clockTime = sessionLength;
   var timerPaused = true;
   var onBreak = false;
   var CLOCK_PIXEL_HEIGHT = 286;

   // Setters / Getters
   function setBreakLength(newLength) {
     breakLength = (newLength <= 0) ? 0 : newLength;
     notify();
   }

   function setSessionLength(newLength) {
     sessionLength = (newLength <= 0) ? 0 : newLength;
     notify();
   }

   function setClockTime(secs) {
     clockTime = secs;
     notify();
   }

   function getClockTime() {
     return clockTime;
   }

   // Timer
   var intervalTimer;

   window.toggleTimer = function() {
     timerPaused = !timerPaused;
     if (!timerPaused) startTimer();
     else stopTimer();
   };

   function startTimer() {
     notify();
     intervalTimer = setInterval(tick, 1000);
   }

   function stopTimer() {
     clearInterval(intervalTimer);
   }

   function tick() {
     if (getClockTime() <= 0) {
       stopTimer();
       toggleBreak();
       return;
     }
     setClockTime(getClockTime() - 1);
   }

   function toggleBreak() {
     onBreak = !onBreak;
     setClockTime(onBreak ? breakLength : sessionLength);
     startTimer();
   }

   /*
     Controls
   */

   window.breakMinus = function() {
     incrementBreakLength(-60);
   };
   window.breakPlus = function() {
     incrementBreakLength(60);
   };
   window.sessionMinus = function() {
     incrementSessionLength(-60);
   };
   window.sessionPlus = function() {
     incrementSessionLength(60);
   };

   window.reset = function() {
     stopTimer();
     timerPaused = true;
     onBreak = false;
     setClockTime(sessionLength);
   };


   // Increment break length. If on break, and timer paused, reset clock to new length.
   function incrementBreakLength(increment) {
     setBreakLength(breakLength + increment);
     if (timerPaused && onBreak) {
       setClockTime(breakLength);
     }
   }

   // Increment session length. If in session, and timer paused, reset clock to new length.
   function incrementSessionLength(increment) {
     setSessionLength(sessionLength + increment);
     if (timerPaused && !onBreak) {
       setClockTime(sessionLength);
     }
   }

   /*
     Update View Function
   */
   var notify = (function() {
     var prevBreakLength;
     var prevSessionLength;

     return function() {
       // Just always update clock.
       document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = formatClockDisplay();
       document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = onBreak ? 'Break' : 'Session';
       document.getElementById('fill').style.backgroundColor = onBreak ? 'red' : 'green';
       document.getElementById('fill').style.height = fillHeight();

       // Update Break Length
       if (prevBreakLength !== breakLength) {
         document.getElementById('break-length').innerHTML = breakLength /  60;
         prevBreakLength = breakLength;
       }

       // Update Session Length
       if (prevSessionLength !== sessionLength) {
         document.getElementById('session-length').innerHTML = sessionLength / 60;
         prevSessionLength = sessionLength;
       }
     };

   })();
   /*
     Helpers
   */
   function formatClockDisplay() {
     var time = getClockTime();
     var mins = Math.floor(time /  60);
     var secs = clockTime % 60;
     secs = secs <  10 ? '0' + secs : secs;
     return (timerPaused && time === sessionLength) ? mins : mins + ':' + secs;
   }

   var fillHeight = (function() {
     var fillBreakLength = breakLength;
     var fillSessionLength = sessionLength;
     var prevOnBreak = onBreak;

     return function() {
       if (timerPaused || prevOnBreak !== onBreak) {
         fillBreakLength = breakLength;
         fillSessionLength = sessionLength;
         prevOnBreak = onBreak;
       }
       var period = onBreak ? fillBreakLength : fillSessionLength;
       var left = getClockTime();
       return (period - left) /  period * CLOCK_PIXEL_HEIGHT + 'px';
     };

   })();

   // init view
   document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
     notify();
   }, false);

 })();
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>PomodoroTimer</h1>

  <div id="control-panel">
    <table align="center">
      <tr>
        <td>BREAK LENGTH</td>
        <td>SESSION LENGTH</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button onclick="breakMinus()">-</button> <span id="break-length">3</span> 
          <button onclick="breakPlus()">+</button>
        </td>
        <td>
          <button onclick="sessionMinus()">-</button> <span id="session-length">7</span> 
          <button onclick="sessionPlus()">+</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="pomodoro" onclick="toggleTimer()">
    <div class="pomoinner">
      <p id="title">Session</p>
      <p id="timer">7</p>
      <span id="fill"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="reset">
    <p>
      <button onclick="reset()">RESET</button>
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
```

See the end product: http://danielrob.github.io/pomodoro-timer/site/

My key question: is there a way I could reduce my global variables or manage the four possible states [(on session, timer running), (on session, timer paused), (on break, timer running), (on break, timer paused) ] more elegantly?

Comment: Can you expand on the purpose of the code? What is "break length" and "session length"?

Comment: @Spike and those confused: [Pomodoro Technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pomodoro_Technique).

Comment: @Spike I have also added a link to the end product.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few notes on your current code:

- IIFE and `"use strict"` - excellent!
- Use of `onclick` - less excellent. Better to use `addEventListener` and keep javascript and HTML separate.
- You can skip the `DOMContentLoaded` handling by simply putting your `script` tag at the end of the `body` tag. That way, all the preceding DOM content will have been loaded when the script starts executing.

Other than that, the icky bits are the state-keeping that you yourself mentioned.

I should add that the UI makes more sense on the page you linked, than it does in the unstyled snippet. Still, even with styling, it wasn't clear what I was supposed to click to actually start the timer. Consider making the big button more "button-like". I know buttons these days are often flat-looking circles, but this flat circle is so large it fails to register as a button - looks more like a purely aesthetic thing. Anyway, that's neither here nor there.

Now, suggestions. I'd suggest wrapping the timers in objects which can encapsulate state for you:

```js
function Timer(duration) {
  this.duration = duration;
  this.remaining = duration;

  this.onupdate = function () {};
  this.onfinish = function () {};
}

Timer.prototype = {
  isRunning: function () {
    return !!this.timer;
  },
  
  hasFinished: function () {
    return this.remaining === 0;
  },
  
  reset: function () {
    this.stop();
    this.remaining = this.duration;
  },

  start: function () {
    if(this.isRunning() || this.hasFinished()) {
      return;
    }
    this.lastTime = Date.now();
    this.timer = setInterval(this.update.bind(this), 100);
  },

  stop: function () {
    clearInterval(this.timer);
    this.timer = null;
  },

  update: function () {
    var delta = Date.now() - this.lastTime;
    this.remaining = Math.max(0, this.remaining - delta);
    this.lastTime = Date.now();
    this.onupdate();
    
    if(this.remaining <= 0) {
      this.stop();
      this.remaining = 0;
      this.running = false;
      this.onfinish();
    }
  },
  
  toString: function () {
    var total = this.remaining / 1000 | 0,
        minutes = total / 60 | 0,
        seconds = total % 60;
    
    return String(minutes) + ":" + ("00" + seconds).slice(-2);
  }
};

// Test (just a 10sec timer)

var t = new Timer(10*1000);

t.onupdate = function () {
  document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = this.toString();
};

t.onfinish = function () {
  document.getElementById("toggle").disabled = true;
};

document.getElementById("toggle").addEventListener("click", function () {
  var clock = document.getElementById("time");
  if(t.isRunning()) {
    clock.style.color = "gray";
    t.stop();
  } else {
    clock.style.color = "black";
    t.start();
  }
}, false);
```

```html
<span id="time">0:10</span>
<br>
<button id="toggle">Toggle timer</button>
```

You could also easily add a `progress` method to the prototype which return a 0-1 number indicating how far in the session/break you are.

As for keeping track of sessions/breaks. I'd create 2 of those `Timer` instances. You can add a `name` argument to the constructor, which you can display on-update, if you want.

Point is, if the session timer `hasFinished()`, then check the break timer. If it too `hasFinished()`, then reset and start the session timer again.

Comment: This is truly excellent, and very much confirms the direction I had taken in the meantime - but a very nice clean presentation of that here, thank you. I was partly getting sidetracked with trying to get more functional: having session/break functions that instantiated a timer with a callback for when it finished which starts a break/session respectively. Worth pursuing? And would it be possible to do all of this fully functionally do you think?

Comment: @Dan Your callback-idea is basically the same as the above; `onfinish` is a callback. It's not passed as an argument to another function, but the result is the same. You probably could do it completely functionally with no explicit object instantiation, only closures - but would you want to? There's no reason to force it in such a direction if you ask me. I'd just stick to modelling it pretty plainly: Two timers, taking turns. Seems more straightforward to me, and easier to extend.

Comment: It seems to me that it's really only *one* timer, with the label and duration toggling between two values.  With a one small change (e.g. give `reset` a duration argument), this could be easily implemented.

Comment: @Edward True, that could be even cleaner. And it'd remove the risk of both timers accidentally running simultaneously.